# Web socket server with IOS client compatibitlty

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, sockets, websocket

I am trying to develop a IOS app which will have a socket connection with the server. For the client side I am planning to use SocketRocket library and also I am trying to code my socket server preferably in nodejs. Can anyone advice me which socket server library should I choose.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an Obj C library for socket.io v0.9.x; (Which uses SocketRocket also)

https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Check out that working example;

https://github.com/saturngod/Socket.io-with-iOS

**Edit:** Swift client also added by socket.io guys; http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/ works with socket.io v1.